# Java : Comparing two String values and building a Unique String

Tags: java, json

I have two Strings as shown below:

```
String A = {"user1":{"cNo":4,"wId":1},"user2":{"cNo":5,"wId":1}}

String B = {"user1":{"cNo":4,"wId":1},"user3":{"cNo":6,"wId":1},"user2":{"cNo":5,"wId":1}}
```

I want  to build a new String C  , which should not contain any duplicates , as shown below (based on values like user1 , user2 , user3 )

Typically it should look like below , without containing any duplicates

```
String C = {"user1":{"cNo":4,"wId":1},"user3":{"cNo":6,"wId":1},"user2":{"cNo":5,"wId":1}}
```

Comment: Your strings are not valid. Did you mean these to be *arrays*?

Comment: This wouldn't even compile - do you mean Javascript instead of Java?

Answer (score 2):

These are JSON documents. Use a JSON library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to work with them. Unmarshall them to say `User` class which implements the `equals()` and `hashCode()` based upon the equality requirements. Then add each of those objects to a java.util.Set and later marshall that Set to JSON using the Gson library.

Comment: Does that library offer methods to de-duplicate in the manner the OP requires? If not, then I think this is only a partial answer.

Comment: I doesn't think there are any json libraries can do that. I thought giving a hint is just enough in this as once she has the object representation then what to be done next is quite intutive.

Comment: @DuncanJones added the sequence of steps

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the opening and closing curly bracket and then use a string splitter and split on the ',' to get each user tag, and add them to a set (only unique ones will get added), then use `set.values()` to get this unique list and print them out? Probably not the most efficient way to do it but should work.